# Is normal a WSDL with a private IP address like SOAP address?

Tags: .net, perl, wsdl, biztalk, nusoap

I want to send requests to a .NET webservice through Internet, but the problem is the SOAP address in the WSDL has a private IP address:

```
<soap:address location="http://10.10.1.1/xxxxx/yyyyyyyyyy.asmx" />
```

And when I try to send some request, with PHP and NuSOAP for example, I get an error with this location:

> HTTP Error: Couldn't open socket connection to server `http://10.10.1.1/xxxxx/yyyyyyyyyy.asmx`, Error (110): Connection timed out

Is this normal? In the other side it's using BizTalk and I think they don't know how to fix it.

I'd prefer a Perl solution like `SOAP::Lite` or `SOAP::XML::Client::DotNet`, but I thought a solution like NuSOAP would be easier than Perl solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As doterob has suggested, BizTalk will need to expose the web-service to the internet for you to be able to access the WSDL and consume it. In doing so, they will expose an internet facing address (e.g. http://web-service.biztalk.com/service.asmx?wsdl)

Once you have a copy of the WSDL, create a message that can be consumed by the web-service and configure your application to use the internet facing address for the web-service. The local network address (10.10.1.1) included in the WSDL assumes that you will be consuming the service from the LAN, not an external network (i.e. the interweb).

I won't go into the security implications sticking a BizTalk web-service live on the internet poses here, but that certainly isn't recommended best practice! I would however recommend that the web-service is secured with Certificate based Authentication at a very minimum.

Answer (score 0):

WSDL has built in a local machine from a brower. You can access to WSDL in Asp.Net if You put the url

```
http://10.10.1.1/xxxxx/yyyyyyyyyy.asmx?WSDL
```

Endpoint can be change, you should put the specific url when you invoke the web service, after or before you put the credentials

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know if I've been misunderstand. I can't change the WSDL because it's not mine.

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved change the endpoint from private address to public address with [XML::Compile::WSDL11](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/XML-Compile-SOAP-2.35/lib/XML/Compile/WSDL11.pod).

Something like this:

```
my $wsdlfile = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file("http://$publicIP/wsdl");
my $wsdl = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new($wsdlfile);
my $call = $wsdl->compileClient(
    'operation',
    server => $publicIP # This change the server address to a specified address
);
```